# ruby for each - how can I output the ticker for all markets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have so far done the following code for an API i am working on:

```
   get "/markets" do
      present Market.all, with: APIv2::Entities::Market
   end
```

this returns me all markets in the following format:

```
[{"id":""usdchf"},{"id":""eurusd"}]
```

further I have developed a ticker for each market:

```
    params do
      use :market
    end
    get "/tickers/:market" do
      ticker = Global[params[:market]].ticker

      { at: ticker[:at],
            ticker: {
              market: ticker[:market],
              buy: ticker[:buy],
              sell: ticker[:sell],
              low: ticker[:low],
              high: ticker[:high],
              last: ticker[:last],
              vol: ticker[:volume],
              trend: ticker[:trend]
            }
      }
    end
```

which outputs me

```
{"at":1409857799,{"market":"usdchf","buy":"0.00125","sell":"0.00982","low":"0.00125","high":"0.00982","last":"0.00982","vol":"0.155","trend":"up"}}
```

all is working as it should.

Now my problem/question is I am working on a new APi view where you see the tickers of all markets with 1 API request. I am stuck in this however. I have so far something along the lines

```
     Market = Market.all, with: APIv2::Entities::Market

     Market.all.each do |t|
      ticker = id.ticker
      present ticker
     end
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction? The final output should be

```
{"at":1409857799,{"market":"usdchf","buy":"0.00125","sell":"0.00982","low":"0.00125","high":"0.00982","last":"0.00982","vol":"0.155","trend":"up"}}
{"at":1409857799,{"market":"eurusd","buy":"0.0322","sell":"0.03242","low":"0.0325","high":"0.01182","last":"0.00214","vol":"2.155","trend":"down"}}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the question, I was wrong to suggest using select. You need collect:

```
Market.all.collect do |market|

  ticker = Global[market['id']].ticker

  { 
    at: ticker[:at],
    ticker: {
      market: ticker[:market],
      buy: ticker[:buy],
      sell: ticker[:sell],
      low: ticker[:low],
      high: ticker[:high],
      last: ticker[:last],
      vol: ticker[:volume],
      trend: ticker[:trend]
     }
   }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I have now:  
    Market.all.each do |t|
       present Rails.cache.read("forex:#{t.id}:ticker") || default_ticker
    end  which gives me the ticker of just the last market. Can you tell me more about the select method?

Comment: Have you read the docs at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select